# How to run PyQt4 app with sudo privelages in Ubuntu and keep the normal user style

Tags: python, linux, qt, ubuntu, pyqt

Ok the title explains it all. But just to clarify.

I have Ubuntu and programed a GUI app with Qt Designer 4 and PyQt4. The program works fine running `python main.py` in terminal.

Last week I made an update and now the program needs `sudo` privelages to start. So I type `sudo python main.py`.

But Oh my GODDDDDDD. What an ungly inteface came up. O.o

And I don't know how to get the realy nice normal-mode interface in my programm and all of my others programs i'll make. Is there any way to set a vaiable to python? Do I need to execute any command line code?

The program is deployed only in Linux machines.

P.S.

I search a lot in the web and couldn't find a working solution.

Comment: Isn't it what `gksudo` is for?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger please explain. I developed a network program and I need to use macchanger. how is it possible every time that a command needs root privelages to pop up a window and not just throw an error?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/202676/sudo-vs-gksudo-difference/726249#726249  If I’m not mistaken, it’s the XAUTHORITY part that will help you keep your “pretty” GUI.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger you mean how to use it? I tried `gksudo python main.py` and nothing happends. Do I need to insert the command inside my program? So When I run a command that need root privelages like `macchanger` to turn the command to `dksudo <command>` inside my python code?

Comment: Maybe you need to install it first. Use it as you would use `sudo`.

Comment: O I installed it. I mean that even with `gksudo` no different appears. I tired `gksudo python main.py` as I pointed

Answer (score 0):

I hope understand correctly, you may have edited the program being "root". PyQt not need to run with superuser if not necessary.

Try to leave your program as root:

```
$sudo chmod 777 yourprogram.py
```

And then exit root and rerun python yourprogram.py

Comment: ok, I tried it and it's the same when I run with root. Install **sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconf** and then **sudo qtconfig** and you can change the style, can be a solution.

Comment: and what can I get with that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky solution.

1. Install qt-qtconf. `sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig`
2. Run `sudo qtconfig` or `gksudo qtconfig`.
3. Change GUI Style to GTK+.

Edited.